# Laptop lid closed and screen disabled once system is up

Tags: windows-10, display, external-display

I have laptop and external monitor. I set up in `power settings` for lid to `Do nothing` when is closed, besides i also set up all options to `Do Nothing` therefore when i close the lid when `system is running` and open lid again my laptop's screen turn on as well. No issue.

Nevertheless when laptop lid is closed and i run `Windows 10` system then when i open laptop's lid once system is up - laptop screen is not turning on. I even do not see that screen in `Display settings`. How to make laptop screen enable once i open lid in this particural case?

**My setup:**

```
> HP 8760W + docking station (video: NVIDIA)
> LG 34 (external monitor)
```

Comment: The way we do this for all such systems is set lid and power options standard for the laptop standalone, then use a dock or docking hub, attach the monitor, keyboard and mouse to the dock, turn on the system via the dock and all works perfectly as it should.

Comment: @John i have docking station for laptop. All options are set to "Nothing" in Power mode. When system is turned on i can close/open lid - and it works fine laptop's screen becoming enabled and that's fine. Nevertheless as mentioned when i boot system and LID of laptop is closed then if you open lid l;aptop's screen is black and not turning on. This is only the case i don;t know how to overcome.

Comment: The set up as I suggested and it should work fine.  By the way, the lid should be closed when you power up via docking station.

Comment: @John i do not get, what to set exactly?

Comment: Start with the laptop, closed and off. Put in the docking station and start with the docking station power button and the external monitor should start when you do this.

Comment: @John I do this. Laptop in docking station - lid closed, external monitor plugged in. When i run system via Power button on docking station system starts and only external monitor got screen working. When i try to open lid it doesn't work it's black and nothing i can do in Desktop settings to enable it.

Comment: When you wish to open the lid, remove from the dock and open the lid. That should work.

Comment: @John No that doesn't work. If i unplug laptop in this case laptop screen is still black